# Info button as UIBarButtonItem doesn't respond to taps

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to programmatically add and info button to my app's navigation. However, it doesn't ever fire the action that I'm registering to it.

```
UIBarButtonItem* infoButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]];
    [infoButton setTarget:self];
    [infoButton setAction:@selector(infoButtonTapped)];
```

The button shows up in my nav bar, but clicking on it doesn't pass into infoButtonTapped

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the target/action to the UIButton. The bar button item behaves differently when it's set up from a UIButton.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```